# How to filter an entire geodatabase by location using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I have a GDB that has national-scale info, but I only need information from a certain state, to which I have the respective polygon.

Is there a way to automatically:

- Iterate through all the feature datasets of the GDB,
- Make the selection by location based on the state polygon, and
- Export it to a new GDB?

If possible, I would like to keep the same structure (as in, the same names for feature datasets and layers within them).

Comment: It's certainly possible, just unwise. Instead you should include the state as an attribute, create an index on that attribute, and add a Definition Query with the state code constraint, and use the existing feature classes as-is.  Note that feature classes are members of feature datasets, and that layers have no relationship to feature datasets at all.

Comment: @BERA I mean feature datasets, each with differente feature classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the feature classes with Walk, create feature layers, select by location, save the selection with select:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap=False #To prevent all selections to be added to the map

workspace = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\test.gdb" #All feature classes here except select feature will be processed
select_feature = "select_feature" #Name of the feature class to select by location with
to_select = [] #A list to hold feature classes to select from
output_database = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\test2.gdb"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename!=select_feature:
            to_select.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
for fc in to_select:
    print(fc)

C:\GIS\data\testdata\test.gdb\fc3
C:\GIS\data\testdata\test.gdb\dataset1\fc1
C:\GIS\data\testdata\test.gdb\dataset2\fc2

arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(in_features=select_feature, out_layer="selector")
for fc in to_select:
    arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(in_features=fc, out_layer="selection")
    
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(in_layer="selection", 
                                           overlap_type="INTERSECT", 
                                           select_features="selector")
    
    
    print(arcpy.GetCount_management("selection"))
    output = os.path.join(output_database, f"{os.path.basename(fc)}_subset")
    arcpy.analysis.Select(in_features="selection", 
                          out_feature_class=output)

92
410
1039
```

[image]